Sharing viewmodel between Android Composabe functions
Are there any problems that arise when sharing the same viewModel between composable functions?

No, that is ok.

If you're using same variables across those components (eg a mutablestate) then changing it from one of the composables will affect state of other composable.
If that is your expected behavior then its okay.

As it was already pointed out in the comments, it is fine to use the same ViewModel instance in different Composables. What I want to point out however are some design aspects.
It sometimes is tempting to just pass the same ViewModel instance down a Composable hierarchy like this:
@Composable
MainComposable(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {
    AComposable(myViewModel)
    BComposable(myViewModel)
}

@Composable
AComposable(myViewModel: MyViewModel) {
    Text(myViewModel.someText)
}

@Composable
BComposable(myViewModel: MyViewModel) {
    Button(onClick = { myViewModel.someFunction() }) {
        Text("Button")
    }
}

The problem with this approach is testability and reusability. For testing each single Composable, you would have to provide a mocked MyViewModel instance. Also, you can only use that Composable with the MyViewModel, and not in other contexts. Finally, you will break the @Preview functionality, as you cannot use Previews with ViewModel parameters.
Tp avoid these disadvantages, you should only pass each Composable the data and functions that it actually needs, instead of passing the whole ViewModel:
@Composable
MainComposable(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {
    AComposable(myViewModel.someText)
    BComposable(myViewModel.someFunction)
}

@Composable
AComposable(someText: String) {
    Text(someText)
}

@Composable
BComposable(someFunction: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = { someFunction() }) {
        Text("Button")
    }
}

This way, AComposable and BComposable are now easily testable and decoupled from the ViewModel. You can use them in any context by simply providing the input data.
